# Sass: Error: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: html, css, sass

Why does the compiler give me an error: Can't find stylesheet to import even though I specified the right path when using the '@use' rule?

[image]

Comment: I'm not using any frameworks.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try `@use ../abstracts/colors @use ../abstracts/fonts`

relative-path / is missing